# Android Firebase strange data mapping

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error from debug mode and I do not know why it happens as everything is supposed to be OK. Some of the data is not null, some of the data is null, does anyone knows why this happens?

[image]

Here is my Firebase code:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    mReference = mDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl("https://basketball-training-app.firebaseio.com/article");

    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

  @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    articleModel = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        articleModel.add(postSnapshot.getValue(ArticleModel.class));
    }



    adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.fragment_article_list_items, articleModel);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleDetailsActivity.class);
        final String postKey = mReference.getKey();
        intent.putExtra("post_key", postKey);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    }
});
  }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

Here is my data from Firebase:

```
[ {
"body" : "Becoming a professional basketball player take ",
"id" : "2",
"photo" : "http://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-640/cme/cme_public_images/www_livestrong_com/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/108/235/489314780_XS.jpg",
"published_date" : "2016-09-19",
"thumb" : "http://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-640/cme/cme_public_images/www_livestrong_com/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/108/235/489314780_XS.jpg",
"title" : "What Training Is Necessary to Become a Professional Basketball Player?",
"video" : ""
}, {
"body" : "It's basketball; these are the best movies of",
"id" : "0",
"photo" : "http://images.contentful.com/7h71s48744nc/1w3KueQHLi2G0oyguoScQE/74af0a5222728503eff818ddcea6865e/coach-carter.jpg",
"published_date" : "2016-09-19",
"thumb" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51FYWuWGPLL._SL160_.jpg",
"title" : "Top Ten Greatest Basketball Movies",
"video" : ""
 }, {
"body" : "Basketball is a very popular sport played all around the ",
 "id" : "1",
 "photo" : "http://mba.org.mt/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/basketball-wallpaper-1280x768-1180x768.jpg",
 "published_date" : "2016-09-19",
 "thumb" : "http://mba.org.mt/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/basketball-wallpaper-1280x768-1180x768.jpg",
  "title" : "Popularity of Basketball Around the World",
 "video" : ""
 } ]
```

And here is model:

```
 @PropertyName("thumb")
private String thumb;

@PropertyName("title")
private String title;

@PropertyName("published_date")
private String published_date;

@PropertyName("photo")
private String photo;

@PropertyName("body")
private String body;

@PropertyName("id")
private String id;

@PropertyName("video")
private String video;

public ArticleModel() {
}

public ArticleModel(String id, String title, String thumb, String published_date, String photo, String body, String video) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.thumb = thumb;
    this.published_date = published_date;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.body = body;
    this.video = video;
}



public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getThumb() {
    return thumb;
}

public void setThumb(String thumb) {
    this.thumb = thumb;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getData() {
    return published_date;
}

public void setData(String published_date) {
    this.published_date = published_date;
}

public String getImage() {
    return photo;
}

public void setImage(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getVideoURI() {
    return video;
}

public void setVideoURI(String video) {
    this.video = video;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setter and getter methods should be the same name with the property's name.

Add or change the getter and setter methods for `photo` and `published_date` to

```
public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPublished_date(String published_date) {
    this.published_date = published_date;
}

public String getPublished_date() {
    return published_date;
}
```

Comment: It is strange, as on asynctask this would not cause a problem... Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomasMaksimavicius you don't need to use asynctask, the ValueEventListener already runs in a separate thread. :)